# Migration of KNKK select query to S/4HANA?

Tags: abap, opensql, s4hana

I have the following SELECT in one of my programs, and I need to modify it due a migration to SAP S/4HANA.

```
SELECT kunnr klimk 
  FROM knkk UP TO 1 ROWS 
  INTO (knkk-kunnr,knkk-klimk) 
 WHERE kunnr = p_kunnr.
```

How can I modify that for it become valid for S4HANA?

`KNKK-KLIMK` [I can replace](https://blogs.sap.com/2020/04/17/conversion-of-credit-management-to-sap-s-4hana/) with `UKMBP_CMS_SGM-CREDIT_LIMIT` but what about `KNKK-KUNNR`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The ATC only suggest the SAP Note 227014 in which it said please eliminate table KNKK in your reports... I find in addition the Note 2706489 - Replacement of KNKK, KNKA, T024B, T024P and T691B tables in SAP Credit Management (FSCM) but there is no info about the KUNNR-field wich I need. @Philipp

Comment: Yes using Eclipse. Running the ATC only brings the above mentioned Note with eliminate the table and tooltip refer also only to this note.. @Philipp

Comment: Why are you actually doing this SELECT? You already got a kunnr in p_kunnr, after all. Do you just want to know if a customer with that number exists? Or do you need to know if there is a specific business process involving that customer?

Comment: yes I want to know if this cusomer exists. @Philipp

Comment: if the only question is, whether the customer exists, than the best is to use table KNA1

Comment: @Tom Try `V_CVI_CUST_LINK` (View for Link between BP and Customer)

Answer (score 0):

**Old Coding:**

```
 CLEAR knkk.
SELECT kunnr klimk 
  FROM knkk UP TO 1 ROWS 
  INTO (knkk-kunnr,knkk-klimk) 
 WHERE kunnr = p_kunnr.
```

**New Coding:**

```
DATA: z_bp TYPE bu_partner_guid.
SELECT partner_guid 
  FROM cvi_cust_link UP TO 1 ROWS 
  INTO z_bp 
 WHERE customer = p_kunnr.
ENDSELECT.

IF z_bp NE ukmbp_cms_sgm-partner.
 CLEAR ukmbp_cms_sgm.
SELECT partner credit_sgmnt 
  FROM ukmbp_cms_sgm UP TO 1 ROWS 
  INTO ( ukmbp_cms_sgm-partner, ukmbp_cms_sgm-credit_sgmnt )                                                        
 WHERE partner = z_bp.
ENDIF.
```

Comment: See also notes [2618445](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/0002618445) and [2576618](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2576618) for settings needed to be done for this to work

Comment: Join over `select... into ... endselect` makes me feel pain, especially on HANA and ABAP 7.4 with enhanced Open SQL syntax.